# Avoid Shuffling with ReduceByKey in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am taking the *coursera Course on Scala Spark*, and I am trying to optimize this snippet:

```
val indexedMeansG = vectors.                                                                                                                                                                 
       map(v => findClosest(v, means) -> v).                                                                                                                                                      
       groupByKey.mapValues(averageVectors)
```

`vectors` is a `RDD[(Int, Int)]`, in order to see the list of dependencies and the lineage of the RDD I've used:

```
println(s"""GroupBy:                                                                                                                                                                         
             | Deps: ${indexedMeansG.dependencies.size}                                                                                                                                           
             | Deps: ${indexedMeansG.dependencies}                                                                                                                                                
             | Lineage: ${indexedMeansG.toDebugString}""".stripMargin)
```

Which shows this:

```
/* GroupBy:                                                                                                                                                                                  
   * Deps: 1                                                                                                                                                                                      
   * Deps: List(org.apache.spark.OneToOneDependency@44d1924)                                                                                                                                      
   * Lineage: (6) MapPartitionsRDD[18] at mapValues at StackOverflow.scala:207 []                                                                                                                 
   *  ShuffledRDD[17] at groupByKey at StackOverflow.scala:207 []                                                                                                                                 
   * +-(6) MapPartitionsRDD[16] at map at StackOverflow.scala:206 []                                                                                                                              
   *  MapPartitionsRDD[13] at map at StackOverflow.scala:139 []                                                                                                                                   
   *      CachedPartitions: 6; MemorySize: 84.0 MB; ExternalBlockStoreSize: 0.0 B; DiskSize: 0.0 B                                                                                                
   *  MapPartitionsRDD[12] at values at StackOverflow.scala:116 []                                                                                                                                
   *  MapPartitionsRDD[11] at mapValues at StackOverflow.scala:115 []                                                                                                                             
   *  MapPartitionsRDD[10] at groupByKey at StackOverflow.scala:92 []                                                                                                                             
   *  MapPartitionsRDD[9] at join at StackOverflow.scala:91 []                                                                                                                                    
   *  MapPartitionsRDD[8] at join at StackOverflow.scala:91 []                                                                                                                                    
   *  CoGroupedRDD[7] at join at StackOverflow.scala:91 []                                                                                                                                        
   *    +-(6) MapPartitionsRDD[4] at map at StackOverflow.scala:88 []                                                                                                                             
   *  |  MapPartitionsRDD[3] at filter at StackOverflow.scala:88 []                                                                                                                               
   *  |  MapPartitionsRDD[2] at map at StackOverflow.scala:69 []                                                                                                                                  
   *  |  src/main/resources/stackoverflow/stackoverflow.csv MapPartitionsRDD[1] at textFile at StackOverflow.scala:23 []                                                                          
   *  |  src/main/resources/stackoverflow/stackoverflow.csv HadoopRDD[0] at textFile at StackOverflow.scala:23 []                                                                                 
   *    +-(6) MapPartitionsRDD[6] at map at StackOverflow.scala:89 []                                                                                                                             
   *  MapPartitionsRDD[5] at filter at StackOverflow.scala:89 []                                                                                                                                  
   *  MapPartitionsRDD[2] at map at StackOverflow.scala:69 []                                                                                                                                     
   *  src/main/resources/stackoverflow/stackoverflow.csv MapPartitionsRDD[1] at textFile at StackOverflow.scala:23 []                                                                             
   *  src/main/resources/stackoverflow/stackoverflow.csv HadoopRDD[0] at textFile at StackOverflow.scala:23 [] */
```

From this `List(org.apache.spark.OneToOneDependency@44d1924)` I deduced no shuffling is being done, Am I right? However, below `ShuffledRDD[17]` is printed, which means in fact there is shuffling.

I've tried to replace that `groupByKey` call with a `reduceByKey`, like this:

```
val indexedMeansR = vectors.                                                                                                                                                              
      map(v => findClosest(v, means) -> v).                                                                                                                                                   
      reduceByKey((a, b) => (a._1 + b._1) / 2 -> (a._2 + b._2) / 2)
```

And its dependencies and lineage are:

```
/* ReduceBy:                                                                                                                                                                                 
   * Deps: 1                                                                                                                                                                                      
   * Deps: List(org.apache.spark.ShuffleDependency@4d5e813f)                                                                                                                                      
   * Lineage: (6) ShuffledRDD[17] at reduceByKey at StackOverflow.scala:211 []                                                                                                                    
   * +-(6) MapPartitionsRDD[16] at map at StackOverflow.scala:210 []                                                                                                                              
   *  MapPartitionsRDD[13] at map at StackOverflow.scala:139 []                                                                                                                                   
   *      CachedPartitions: 6; MemorySize: 84.0 MB; ExternalBlockStoreSize: 0.0 B; DiskSize: 0.0 B                                                                                                
   *  MapPartitionsRDD[12] at values at StackOverflow.scala:116 []                                                                                                                                
   *  MapPartitionsRDD[11] at mapValues at StackOverflow.scala:115 []                                                                                                                             
   *  MapPartitionsRDD[10] at groupByKey at StackOverflow.scala:92 []                                                                                                                             
   *  MapPartitionsRDD[9] at join at StackOverflow.scala:91 []                                                                                                                                    
   *  MapPartitionsRDD[8] at join at StackOverflow.scala:91 []                                                                                                                                    
   *  CoGroupedRDD[7] at join at StackOverflow.scala:91 []                                                                                                                                        
   *    +-(6) MapPartitionsRDD[4] at map at StackOverflow.scala:88 []                                                                                                                             
   *  |  MapPartitionsRDD[3] at filter at StackOverflow.scala:88 []                                                                                                                               
   *  |  MapPartitionsRDD[2] at map at StackOverflow.scala:69 []                                                                                                                                  
   *  |  src/main/resources/stackoverflow/stackoverflow.csv MapPartitionsRDD[1] at textFile at StackOverflow.scala:23 []                                                                          
   *  |  src/main/resources/stackoverflow/stackoverflow.csv HadoopRDD[0] at textFile at StackOverflow.scala:23 []                                                                                 
   *    +-(6) MapPartitionsRDD[6] at map at StackOverflow.scala:89 []                                                                                                                             
   *  MapPartitionsRDD[5] at filter at StackOverflow.scala:89 []                                                                                                                                  
   *  MapPartitionsRDD[2] at map at StackOverflow.scala:69 []                                                                                                                                     
   *  src/main/resources/stackoverflow/stackoverflow.csv MapPartitionsRDD[1] at textFile at StackOverflow.scala:23 []                                                                             
   *  src/main/resources/stackoverflow/stackoverflow.csv HadoopRDD[0] at textFile at StackOverflow.scala:23 [] */
```

This time, the dependency is `ShuffleDependency` and I am not able to understand why.

Since the RDD is a pair which **keys are Ints**, and therefore have an ordering,  I've also tried to modified the partitioner and use a `RangePartitioner`, but it doesn't improve either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `reduceByKey` operation still involves a shuffle, as it's still required to ensure that all items with the same key become part of the same partition.

However, this will be a much smaller shuffle operation than a `groupByKey` operation.  A `reduceByKey` will perform the reduction operation within each partition before shuffling, thus reducing the amount of data to be shuffled.

Comment: But accordingly to the output of `dependencies`, `groupByKey` has an `OneToOneDependency`, which does not involve shuffling, and `reduceByKey` has `ShuffleDependency`, which involve shuffling. Why?

Comment: The `OneToOneDependency` corresponds to the `mapValues` call, not the `groupByKey` call.  If that is removed, you should notice the `ShuffleDependency`.  Also, note the `ShuffledRDD` in the `groupByKey` lineage.